# Run default scripts on HSQL server startup from docker

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile, hsqldb

I am creating a container in which I want a few hsql scripts to run(I am the image to hold all the tables/schema) as soon as the hsql DB server has started.

I have the below line in the ***entrypoint.sh*** file, which is starting the server instance

```
java ${java_vm_parameters} -cp /opt/hsqldb/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.Server -database.0 "file:/opt/database/${hsqldb_database_name}
```

I have tried putting my scripts in the same directory where the *.script/ *.log hoping these scripts to run and it did not work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are there errors? Any logs you can provide? Run the command from an actual docker exec session, not just `docker run` alone

Comment: @cricket_007 No errors. The scripts get copied but the tables do not get created.

Comment: @cricket_007 I am sure if that even is a correct approach

Comment: I'm not asking if the files are copied, but if the Java process ran. If it did, you should see at least some output from just running `java`

Comment: Yes, The java process ran and the server has started.

Comment: Okay, and which script file are you expecting to be ran? Why are you expecting the whole directory of scripts to be scanned?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161583/discussion-between-mukund-gandlur-and-cricket-007).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an HSQLDB database named `hsqldb_database_name` and run your SQL scripts using a tool such as SqlFile (supplied with HSQLDB) against this database. You then put the .script and other files for this database in the directory before starting the Server.